# No puedo depurar en visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Me acabo de instalar Visual Studio 2017, he de mencionar que al momento de instalarlo en una parte salió el mensaje que no existía mi usuario (Sólo apareció una vez), sin embargo le di al continuar. Ahora al tratar de ejecutar el código, me aparece el CMD de manera breve, se cierra y vuelve donde estaba.

[image: "El código que viene por defecto"]

[image: Al ejecutarlo, brevemente se cierra sin hacer algo]

Comment: Hola compañero el problema es algo muy simple. Lo que pasa es que system.write("Tu mensaje"); no detiene la ejecucion del programa entonces lee la linea y se cierra porque el programa no hace nada mas. Puedes utilizar Console.ReadLine(); o Console.ReadKey(); para detener tu programa hasta que des enter o pique una tecla

Comment: Para depurar te falta agregar un punto de interrupcion, boton derecho cerca de donde estan numerados tus lienas de codigo y porsupuesto iniciar la aplicacion en modo depuracion,

Comment: para la próxima en lugar de colocar una imagen del código colócalo como texto; a la comunidad no le gusta re-escribir el código que tu pegas en una imagen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

o

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

[ReadLine()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_ReadLine) Espera a que des eneter y [ReadKey()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) cualquier tecla. 
Si vienes de c++ es como un system("PAUSE"); tu programa funciona bien y no es problema de la instalación solo es que no lo detienes y acaba de ejecutarse por eso el cierre inmediato

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente fue eso

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que todo se ejecuta tan rápido que se cierra de manera casi inmediata, claro, una vez se ejecuta tu código. Después de `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");` debes agregar una sentencia que deje en pausa, puede ser `Console.ReadKey();` que espera que presiones una tecla. Esta la colocas justo después del `Console.write("Hello World");`

Saludos

Comment: Efectivamente, ya en el cmd aparece el Hello World, es raro siendo que es lo que coloca Visual Studio por defecto, ¡Muchas gracias!